# How to redirect terminal output to vim or get `vim like` behaviour in terminal output

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, terminal, terminal-buffer

How to get vim keybindings at terminal output so I can navigate/operate at terminal output like in vim or get smooth shell command processing in vim. For example I type:

`ifconfig`

an i want to make moves to `ipaddres` location, then copy it and paste into command line.

I already know solution inside VIM like:

`read ! ifconfig`

but it I am looking for more persistent solution that will work smoothly for a long run.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about vi/vim but asking for vim-like features in other apps.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to simply issue `terminal ifconfig` (vim8 or vim7 with a lot of patches).

This will open a vim-buffer with the result.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the Vi-mode in your terminal. You can do something like this:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command
```

You can further customize keybindings, as described in this article:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal

Another way would be to probably pipe it out to something like "less" and then use a tool similar to vim-less:
https://github.com/groenewege/vim-less

Answer (score 1):

With [tmux](https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/) (terminal multiplexer) you can do select/copy/paste of terminal screen contents using Vim commands. When you're in a `tmux` session run your command(s) outputting to terminal (stdout). Then hit "prefix" + `[` to get in "copy mode". From there you can navigate with Vim commands like `Ctrl-U`, optionally select some text using Visual mode and yank with commands like `y`. Quit copy mode and you can paste anywhere in the `tmux` session (with "prefix" + `]`).

Note: "prefix" is a special keystroke used to initiate most `tmux` commands. It is `Ctrl-B` by default but configurable.